# Создание сайта на django

Tags: django

Привет. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, книги, блоги, циклы статей на русском, про создание сайта на Джанго. Причем на примере конкретного, полноценного сайта с регистрацией, подтверждением e-mail ну и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

http://djbook.ru/

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html

Книги:
Django. Подробное руководство. 2-е издание

Django. Разработка веб-приложений на Python

По последней книге я учился.